# Installing Ubuntu alongside complicated Windows 8 setup

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, installation, multi-boot

I just bought an Asus computer with Windows 8 on it, and I'd like to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside it. To begin with, I went in to disk management to shrink the main OS partition to make room for Ubuntu. When I got there, though, I saw an interesting arrangement.

[image: Original partition scheme]

OK, weird. **Two** recovery partitions, a system partition, and the OS partition. Fine, whatever. I went ahead and shrank the OS partition by as much as I could, 346,229 MB.

[image: Partition scheme with shrunken OS partition]

I then booted Ubuntu from a live USB and proceeded to install. I chose to set up partitions manually, putting a 1024 MB swap partition and the remaining size `/` partition in the freed up space. I pressed the install button to accept that configuration and install, but I got this error:

[image: Error about boot code space]

What do I need to do here? I thought among all those partitions one of them would already be the right type to hold that code. Also, if I choose the Ubuntu installer's default "install alongside windows", will this be set up correctly automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your computer uses UEFI, and so a GPT partitioning table. GPT has no MBR to install GRUB into, so a partition has to exist for GRUB to be installed in instead.

Comment: Any recommendations as to where to put this partition? Does it need to be at the beginning of the drive?

Comment: I don't think so, but I may be wrong. As far as I know, it only has to be set as a bios_grub boot partition.